# How to stop auto update Centos7?

Tags: centos, upgrade

I need to stop auto update my Centos7. How we can stop Auto update?
How to update it as per schedule time? Please help me.

Comment: Don't worry, IBM will stop them soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways that packages might be automatically updated, one is `yum-cron`.  If that package is installed, check the `/etc/yum/yum-cron.conf` file and set

```
apply_updates = no
```

If that file doesn’t exist or that setting is already set, you will have to investigate what is calling `yum` on a regular basis.